# algorithm to draw a line on triangular grid

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I am trying to implement an algorithm which draws a line connecting 2 given points namely initial point (x0,y0) and a final point (x1,y1). The algorithm should connect the points by plotting pixels for which I will be using  header file in CPP.

The Brsenham algorithm for drawing lines on square grid already exits as explained in this link - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-line-generation-algorithm/

How can I write the algorithm which works for triangular grid? This is how the triangular grid looks:

[image: Triangular grid image]

Comment: What coordinate system are you using for your triangular grid?  How do you label the faces?  [This page](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/grids/) seems like a good place to start.

Comment: i am using Cartesian coordinate system..unfortunately i cannot post any image ...otherwise i would have shown the coordinate system

Comment: Why can't you post any images? There's an image button right there on the edit page. Until you've got enough rep, it will only show up as a link, but at least we can go look at it. And someone with more rep can edit the actual image into the question for you.

Comment: If you have a 2-axis coordinate system, what happens if you just apply the Bresneham algorithm as is?  It might "just work".

Comment: @beaker thanks 4 helping me with the image thing. now i have posted the image of triangular grid

Comment: @AShelly actually the bresenham algo works for square grid but I have to do this for triangular grid as shown in the image..

Comment: the image is useless without some indication of how you are numbering the triangular pixels.